# Uso optimo de condicionales SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, condiciones, optimización

Buen día, tengo código que intento optimizar tanto por recursos así como de hacerlo de una manera "mejor".

Muestro mi código (a forma de lógica para pruebas) que se tenia inicialmente y lo que he realizado.

- La estructura de la tabla `#T0` es como la tabla original y esta no se puede cambiarse por permisos.
- La forma de visualizar la tabla debe ser como los ejemplos, ya que es petición para detalle de los datos.

```
    IF OBJECT_ID('TempDB..#T0') IS NOT NULL BEGIN   DROP TABLE #T0 END
    IF OBJECT_ID('TempDB..#T1') IS NOT NULL BEGIN   DROP TABLE #T1 END
    IF OBJECT_ID('TempDB..#T2') IS NOT NULL BEGIN   DROP TABLE #T2 END

    CREATE TABLE #T0(
        [#] INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
        [#_Resp_1] NVARCHAR(5) NULL
    )

    INSERT INTO #T0 ([#_Resp_1])
    VALUES ('2'),('4'),('8'),('9'),('0'),('NULL')


    /*Como estaba*/
    SELECT
     [NPS_0] = CASE WHEN [#_Resp_1] <>'null' THEN CASE WHEN [#_Resp_1] = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ELSE '' END 
    ,[NPS_1] = CASE WHEN [#_Resp_1] <>'null' THEN CASE WHEN [#_Resp_1] = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ELSE '' END
    ,[NPS_2] = CASE WHEN [#_Resp_1] <>'null' THEN CASE WHEN [#_Resp_1] = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ELSE '' END
    ,[NPS_3] = CASE WHEN [#_Resp_1] <>'null' THEN CASE WHEN [#_Resp_1] = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ELSE '' END
    ,[NPS_4] = CASE WHEN [#_Resp_1] <>'null' THEN CASE WHEN [#_Resp_1] = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ELSE '' END
    ,[NPS_5] = CASE WHEN [#_Resp_1] <>'null' THEN CASE WHEN [#_Resp_1] = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ELSE '' END
    ,[NPS_6] = CASE WHEN [#_Resp_1] <>'null' THEN CASE WHEN [#_Resp_1] = 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ELSE '' END
    ,[NPS_7] = CASE WHEN [#_Resp_1] <>'null' THEN CASE WHEN [#_Resp_1] = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ELSE '' END
    ,[NPS_8] = CASE WHEN [#_Resp_1] <>'null' THEN CASE WHEN [#_Resp_1] = 8 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ELSE '' END
    ,[NPS_9] = CASE WHEN [#_Resp_1] <>'null' THEN CASE WHEN [#_Resp_1] = 9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ELSE '' END
    INTO #T1
    FROM #T0


    /*Lo que hice*/
    SELECT 
            [NPS_0] = IIF([#_Resp_1] = 0, 1,0),
            [NPS_1] = IIF([#_Resp_1] = 1, 1,0),
            [NPS_2] = IIF([#_Resp_1] = 2, 1,0),
            [NPS_3] = IIF([#_Resp_1] = 3, 1,0),
            [NPS_4] = IIF([#_Resp_1] = 4, 1,0),
            [NPS_5] = IIF([#_Resp_1] = 5, 1,0),
            [NPS_6] = IIF([#_Resp_1] = 6, 1,0),
            [NPS_7] = IIF([#_Resp_1] = 7, 1,0),
            [NPS_8] = IIF([#_Resp_1] = 8, 1,0),
            [NPS_9] = IIF([#_Resp_1] = 9, 1,0)
    INTO #T2
    FROM #T0
    WHERE [#_Resp_1] NOT IN ('NULL')

    --SELECT * FROM #T0
    SELECT * FROM #T1
    SELECT * FROM #T2
```

¿Hay alguna forma mejor de poder solucionar este caso de una forma mas optima?

Alguien alguna vez me comentaba que se podría por una tabla de configuración (mediante otra tabla temporal con JOIN) pero sinceramente no veo la forma de implementarla así.

Agradezco de antemano su apoyo, saludos.

Comment: Si no vas a usar los resultados más de una vez, no necesitas usar tablas temporales para almacenar los resultados. Fuera de eso, solo hay cosas extrañas como el usar cadenas con la palabra null en vez de valores null, o comparar valores enteros contra una columna nvarchar (cosa que puede causar errores).

Comment: La idea de las tablas temporales es para un posterior uso de datos, esto apenas es lo inicial. Para lo de los valores null, pues no lo discuto, así esta la estructura dentro de la empresa, no puedo cambiarla, supongo lo dejaron así por la cantidad de datos que se manejan o por algo. Saludos.

Comment: No me queda claro que es lo que quieres mejorar. Si solo buscas una opinión, claramente la nueva forma que usas, parece más compacta y clara, no necesariamente más eficiente. De todas formas, siendo estrictos, la comparación debiera hacerse como una cadena ya que así es la columna: `IIF([#_Resp_1] = '0', 1,0)`. Y también el condicional original podría simplificarse así: `[NPS_0] = CASE WHEN [#_Resp_1] = '0' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`